# What changes do I need to make for a more complex view?

Tags: android

I am following the code from Android Developers:[RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)
, and I want a more complex layout for a single item in the RecyclerView (I want it to have an image, and 2 text views inside a RelativeLayout, rather than just a single TextView without any Layout parent.
The code works when my `my_text_view.xml` file contains just a TextView like so:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    tools:text="Hello John Doe" />
```

But when I try to change it to a more complex layout, that contains an ImageView and 2 TextViews under a RelativeLayout, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:padding="6dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/secondLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="26dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="Description"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstLine"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Example application"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then the app will crash.
I really don't know where I should apply more changes, I am quite lost in their explanation on holders, and adapters, and layout managers. What exactly in their code should be changed? I basically copied their code if you need reference (And it worked, that's why I didn't copy their code here)

Edit: I believe the changes should be somewhere in this code, but I don't know where and how exactly

```
package com.example.lastlocation.recyclerviewer;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private String[] mDataset;

    // Provide a reference to the views for each data item
    // Complex data items may need more than one view per item, and
    // you provide access to all the views for a data item in a view holder
    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // each data item is just a string in this case
        public TextView mTextView;
        public MyViewHolder(TextView v) {
            super(v);
            mTextView = v;
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MyAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {


        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element
        holder.mTextView.setText(mDataset[position]);

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

Comment: you have to use an adapter that will inflate this layout and use it it is a more complex than you thought it will be

Comment: But where are the changes? I really can't make it work and I've tried, but if I paste my code here it would be a  mess. Edit: I added the code part where I think the changes should be made. (The adapter part) Although I am not sure how exactly to change them

Answer (score 0):

If you modify the contents of the item view XML file, you will also have to modify your `ViewHolder` class and your Adapter's `onCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` methods.

In your new version, you have a RelativeLayout, an ImageView, and two TextViews. You probably don't need to do anything to the RelativeLayout, so your `ViewHolder` will only have references to the ImageView and TextViews:

```
public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public final ImageView icon;
    public final TextView firstLine;
    public final TextView secondLine;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        icon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        firstLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
        secondLine = itemView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
    }
}
```

Your onCreateViewHolder() method doesn't need to change much. Mostly you just need to remove the cast, since now you're no longer inflating a TextView object:

```
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
```

Your onBindViewHolder() method needs to change to use the new views you've specified:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.whatever);
    holder.firstLine.setText("Hello");
    holder.secondLine.setText("World");
}
```